# Public key encrypted SMS J2ME

Tags: mobile, java-me, cryptography, sms, bouncycastle

I need to make an SMS application which encrypt the message going trough it.
I'm planning to add these features to application,

```
1)Generate key-pairs.
2)Send the public key to other party as a SMS.
3)Encrypt the message using a given publickey.
4)Decrypt the received message using a privatekey.
5)Manage more than one key.
```

Please let me know if there is any library(prefer open-source) that maybe help to do this.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Comment: Yeah a Bit,I found a library called `lcrypto`.But it's too big.I mean the final product is too heavy to run on law end phones.

Comment: Do you have a jar file size limitation?

Comment: Yes,Most of the phones that I'm planning this to use have size limitations.

Comment: Do you need to create a single jar for all phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading lcrypto-j2me-147.tar.gz (latest version as of today) from [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html), we can use the compiled binaries at zips folder: cldc_bccore_classes.zip is **1.7MB**, cldc_bcpg_classes.zip is **260.5KB** and cldc_bcpkix_classes.zip is **370.5KB**.

There is a good example of how to use bccore [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/encrypting-decrypting-text-messages-with-bouncy-castle-crypt.html), but you should try to use only bcpg (which is the smallest) as shown [here](http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/05/13/revisited-pgp-encryptiondecryption-in-java/).